# How to change the class name using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a check box and I want to check and uncheck based on a variable.
Bellow is the code for check box. I am using `Bootstrap` check box.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <label class="control-label" for="pwd">My Check-Box:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <span class="button-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"  id="myCheckBox"/>
        <button id="myCheckBoxButton" type="button" class="btn-chk" data-color="success" ></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the check-box is checked and unchecked,it look like bellow

Checked
[image]

Unchecked
[image]

I tried multiple ways to check and uncheck the check box.
this is what, I tried

```html
 $('#myCheckBox').prop('checked',true);
$('#myCheckBox').attr("disabled", false);
$('#myCheckBox').attr("disabled", "true");


$('#myCheckBoxButton').prop('checked',true);
$('#myCheckBoxButton').attr("disabled", false);
$('#myCheckBoxButton').attr("disabled", "true");
```

Nothing works for me.
It works if I am using normal check box.

After that I debug the code using firebug. 
**Here I see the code When checkBox is checked.**

```html
<input id="myCheckBox" class="hidden" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<button id="myCheckBoxButton" class="btn-chk btn-success active" data-color="success" type="button">
<i class="state-icon glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i>
</button>
```

Now I tried This.
because check-box is a button so I thought lets change the class.

*Suppose flag is a variable in Which check box check and uncheck depends on.*

```js
if (flag == '0') {
  $('#myCheckBox').attr('checked', false);
  $("#myCheckBoxButton").addClass("btn-chk btn-default-chk");
} else {
  $("#myCheckBoxButton").removeClass("btn-chk btn-default-chk");
  $("#myCheckBoxButton").removeClass("state-icon glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked");
  $("#myCheckBoxButton").addClass(" glyphicon glyphicon-check");
  $("#myCheckBoxButton").addClass("btn-chk btn-success active");
}
```

Now I am able to check, but it looks weird.
[image]

When I debug using fire bug I saw That changes in the code.

```html
<input id="myCheckBox" class="hidden" type="checkbox">
<button id="myCheckBoxButton" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check btn-chk btn-success active" data-color="success" type="button">
<i class="state-icon glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i>
</button>
```

I can see clearly there is an extra class added in button

`<button id="myCheckBoxButton" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check btn-chk btn-success active" data-color="success" type="button">`

How do I fix this can one help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Look here. It is working fine. Or are you trying something else?

```js
var flag = 0;
    if (flag == '0') {
    $('#myCheckBox').prop('checked', true);
  $("#myCheckBoxButton").addClass("btn-chk btn-default-chk");
} else {
  $("#myCheckBoxButton").removeClass("btn-chk btn-default-chk");
  $("#myCheckBoxButton").removeClass("state-icon glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked");
  $("#myCheckBoxButton").addClass(" glyphicon glyphicon-check");
  $("#myCheckBoxButton").addClass("btn-chk btn-success active");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <label class="control-label" for="pwd">My Check-Box:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <span class="button-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"  id="myCheckBox" />
        <button id="myCheckBoxButton" type="button" class="btn-chk" data-color="success" ></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there, it works fine based on flag variable, it is unchecking and checking.

Answer (score 0):

It is posible to change class name. visit this link

http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/